# After replot the chart grid lines are disappear

Tags: jqplot

I am using jqplot charting library to draw the bar chart in my application.
I have used following code to draw the horizontal bar chart.

```
   var plot = $.jqplot('chart', [dataSlices], {
                seriesDefaults: {
                    shadow: false,
                    renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
                    pointLabels: { show: true, location: 'e', edgeTolerance: -55 },
                    rendererOptions: {
                        barDirection: 'horizontal',
                        barMargin: 5,
                        highlightMouseOver: false,
                        fillToZero: true
                    }
                },
                axesDefaults: {

                },
                axes: {
                    grid: {
                        drawBorder: false
                    },
                    xaxis: {
                        pad: 0,
                        tickOptions: {
                            show: true,
                            mark: 'cross',
                            thousandsSeparator: ',',
                            formatString: "%d"
                        },
                        numberTicks: null,
                        min: null,
                        max: null,
                        showTickMarks: true
                    },
                    yaxis: {
                        renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                        ticks: yAxisLabels,
                        tickOptions: {
                            showMark: false,
                            showGridline: false
                        }
                    }
                },
                grid: {
                    gridLineColor: '#ffffff', /**/
                    borderColor: '#509790',
                    background: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
                    shadowWidth: 0,
                    borderWidth: 0,
                    shadow: false
                },
                series: [{ color: '#f39f02' }]
            });

            $.jqplot.thousandsSeparator = ',';
            //$.jqplot.formatString = "%'d";
            gridCanvas = $($('.jqplot-grid-canvas')[0])
            seriesCanvas = $($('.jqplot-series-canvas')[0])
            gridCanvas.detach();
            seriesCanvas.after(gridCanvas);
           plot.replot({ resetAxes: true });
```

I am getting the chart without grid lines.
Is there any idea, how to do this?

Comment: GridLineColor set to white (#FFFFFF) explains why you aren't viewing vertical lines. BorderWidth set to 0 explains why you aren't viewing border of your plot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the following lines after replot, you will get the expected result

```
                gridCanvas = $($(item + ' .jqplot-grid-canvas')[0])
                seriesCanvas = $($(item + ' .jqplot-series-canvas')[0])
                gridCanvas.detach();
                seriesCanvas.after(gridCanvas);
```

I tried its working fine for me,.

Answer (score 0):

GridLineColor set to white (#FFFFFF) explains why you aren't wiewing vertical lines.

BorderWidth set to 0 explains why you aren't viewing borders of your plot (drawn with a size of 0px)

If you doesn't need particular color and/or size of your grid (vertical lines and border) remove the **grid** part of your code.
If you need particular color and/or size choose carefully your values (#FFFFFF if your background if already white - or a borderWidth of 0px) :

```
grid: {
 gridLineColor: '#FF0000',
 borderColor: '#509790',
 background: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
 shadowWidth: 0,
 borderWidth: 2,
 shadow: false
},
```

Please see working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/AnthonyLeGovic/282bm/) (I have delete yAxisLabels and add fictional data in order to draw a plot)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Actual issue is with the grid lines in the xaxis:

 xaxis: { pad: 0,  tickOptions: { show: true, mark: 'cross',
thousandsSeparator: ',', formatString: "%d", showGridline: true }, numberTicks: null, min: null,
                        max: null, showTickMarks: true },

Grid lines are disappear whenever do the replot.

Please find the images here:
http://sdrv.ms/19f1xWR, 
#1 First image is without xaxis gridlines with replot function.
#2 Second image is with xaxis gridlines without replot.[This is the expected output)